# How to replace columns names in pandas but based on dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 different dfs.
Example of column names:

```
df1 = a1, b1, c1, d1
df2 = b1, c1, e1
df3 = a1, b1, c1
```

And I created dicrionary like this:

```
dict = {a1:art1, b1:base1, c1:cell1, d1:dan1, e1:el1}
```

It's possible to rename column not using for loop? I mean, I tried to do that by rename function in for loop, but then I need to loop through all dataframe and it's not looks good in code and I think it's not that fast as should be.

My excpected result is:

```
df1 = art1, base1, cell1, dan1
df2 = base1, cell1, el1
df3 = art1, base1, cell1
```

And I found some answers on stack but nothing fit to my problem, where I have one dictionary and few df with not unique columns names.

Comment: What is exactly wrong with a for loop? I think this is a perfect use case for a for loop

Comment: Renaming columns is a fast operation

Comment: Ok, it's work fine, but is it not possible to do it by map() or something like that? I tried but I filed. About loop, sometimes I have 4000+ columns and 50-60 frames, and I just looking for something more pythonic.

Comment: There is no way to do this without a loop... `for df in df_list: df.rename(columns=your_dict, inplace=True)`. Btw `dict` is a reserved word, don't use it as variable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comprehension:

```
d = {'a1': 'art1', 'b1': 'base1', 'c1': 'cell1', 'd1': 'dan1', 'e1': 'el1'}

df1, df2, df3 = [df.rename(columns=d) for df in [df1, df2, df3]]
```

A simple loop:

```
for df in [df1, df2, df3]:
    df.rename(columns=d, inplace=True)
```

Using `map`:

```
df1, df2, df3 = list(map(lambda df: df.rename(columns=d), [df1, df2, df3]))
```

At the end, IMHO the simple loop with `inplace=True` is the most elegant.

Comment: Oh awesome ! Actually I didin't know that I can just replace it in that way in loop . I just looped each column, check if it's in dictionary and if yes I just used replaced for each column separately. Indeed ur loop looks elegant! Thank u!